# Refer a set of properties in a spring bean

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, dependency-injection

I am using spring and having a requirement where I need to configure lots of beans. ex :

```
<bean name="PC_Name" class="com.stack.Exchange">
 <property name="firstName" value="jack"/>
 <property name="lastName"  value="nicolas"/>
</bean>

<bean name="Mobile_Name" class="com.stack.Exchange">
  <property name="firstName" value="jack"/>
  <property name="lastName"  value="nicolas"/>
</bean>
```

Now, as in both above beans I am using same properties and same values.
Is there any way to write these properties in a common tag and inject that in above beans. some thing like :

```
<bean name="PC_Name" class"com.stack.Exchange">
  <properties name="nameReference"/> 
</bean>

<bean name="Mobile_Name" class"com.stack.Exchange">
 <properties name="nameReference"/> 
</bean> 

 <properties name="nameReference">
    <property name="firstName" value="jack"/>
    <property name="lastName"  value="nicolas"/>
 </properties>
```

I know it can be achieved by Defining another class with firstName and lastName variables and inject that class in the required bean.
But I do not want to change code which has been written already in com.stack.Exchange class.

Thanks
Nitin

Comment: was this useful for your requirement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the possibility to create a Bean definition template. In this bean you have to declare an attribute "abstract" with value true. You should not specify class attribute in it.

```
    <bean id="beanTemplate" abstract="true">
       <property name="firstName" value="jack"/>
       <property name="lastName"  value="nicolas"/>
    </bean>
    <bean name="PC_Name" class"com.stack.Exchange" parent="beanTemplate">
    </bean>
    <bean name="Mobile_Name" class"com.stack.Exchange" parent="beanTemplate">
    </bean>
```